# With basic iterative method $Mx_{k+1} = Nx_k + b$, show that $||x_k-x||_2 \leq \dfrac{\rho(G)}{1-\rho(G)}||x_k-x_{k-1}||_2$

Tags: normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius

With $Mx_{k+1} = Nx_k + b$, define $G=M^{-1}N$

show that $$||x_k-x||_2 \leq \dfrac{\rho(G)}{1-\rho(G)}||x_k-x_{k-1}||_2$$

where $\rho(G)$ is the spectral radius of G

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is $x$ the limit of $x_k$?

Comment: $x$ is the exact solution of the iterative method.

Comment: And how exactly does that answer differ from a simple "yes, $x$ is the limit $x_k$", that you would choose to give such a hackneyed description?

Comment: I'm Sorry. Sure! If the Iterative method is convergent, x is the limit of $x_k$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

You [already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450375/spectral-radius-of-g-m%e2%88%921n-approximately-satisfies-rhog-approx-frac) that
$$
x_{k+1}−x_k=G(x_k−x_{k−1}).
$$
Since $x$ is the fixed point, it satisfies $(I-G)x=M^{-1}b$ so we have
$$
x_{k+1}=Gx_k+M^{-1}b=Gx_k+(I-G)x.
$$
Put these two together to get
$$
x-x_k=(I-G)^{-1}G(x_k−x_{k−1}).
$$